# How can I consume oData from a service in SAP UI5, while not using the Web IDE?

Tags: odata, phpstorm, sapui5

I would like to display data from a oData model in SAP UI5.

```
"dataSources": {
            "ZSM_APPLIKATION_SRV": {
                "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZSM_APPLIKATION_SRV/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "2.0",
                    "localUri": "localService/ZSM_APPLIKATION_SRV/metadata.xml"
                }
            }
        },

"models": {
    "i18n": {
        ...
        }
    },
    "oData": {
        "dataSource": "ZSM_APPLIKATION_SRV"
    }
}
```

As you can see I already added the oData service to the manifest.json and specified the model "oData" to represent this service.

I would now like to display the services data in a table. When adding the property `items="{oData>/UserSet}"` to the table it works fine when launching the application with the Web IDE and all the data is displayed. 
Instead of using the Web IDE I use PhpStorm and a local Apache Web Server to test the UI5 app. 
When using the solution, which works with the Web IDE I keep getting an Error in the Chrome console and the data won't be displayed in the table:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
```

So the Web IDEs webserer seems to find the service without a problem, while both the local apache server and the built-in PhpStorm server won't find it.

I also tried to enter the full service URI in the manifest.json

```
"uri": "http://xxx:50020/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZSM_APPLIKATION_SRV/"
```

Doing so will result in getting another error at the chrome console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx:50020/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZSM_APPLIKATION_SRV/$metadata?sap-language=DE. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Is there any way now to connect to my service and consume data without using the Web IDE? How can I fix this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm requires correct deployment setup to be configured (see [tutorial](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deploying+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm)) - IDE can't detect path mappings in complex projects so you would have to configure deployment & path mappings for this to work from inside IDE.